# MYSQL Select from AND Where

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the content of one cell of my table.
My code is this->

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
// Connect to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*!#@%#") or die(mysql_error()); 

//Select DB
mysql_select_db("yplay") or die(mysql_error()); 

$PlayList = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=" . $username);
$videos = $PlayList["playlist"];
```

The content of that one Cell must be in $videos

Thanks

Comment: As username is likely to be a string, it should probably be quoted (and escaped) - but learn to use MySQLi with prepared statements and bind variables rather than the insecure and end-of-life MySQL extension

Comment: Please tell me you 1) haven't posted your password & 2) do not have a trailing `^` after your closing syntax?

Comment: No i dont have posted my password and no i dont have taht trailing in my script. But how do i select a cell from a database?

Answer (score 2):

```
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*!#@%#") or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db("yplay") or die(mysql_error()); 

$PlayListQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=" . $username." LIMIT 1");

$PlayList = mysql_fetch_assoc($PlayListQuery); // Do something with the result set from the query

$videos = $PlayList["playlist"];
```

Comment: @MortezaSepehri Referring OP to PDO will be of no use for the package being created, mainly because `mysql_*` and `pdo` are different things + May I suggest adding an explanation to your answer for other users who may come to this question looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
// Connect to your Database 

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*!#@%#";
$db_name = "yplay";

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "*!#@%#") or die(mysql_error()); 

//Select DB
mysql_select_db($db_name, $conn) or die(mysql_error()); 


$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslahes($username));    // to prevent mysql injections             
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $videos = $row["playlist"];
}
else
{
    echo "No username exists in the table";
}
```